# Function that inserts a new value in the middle of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I have to use a.splice(index, 0, value) to solve.

this is what I have so far, but the value for final is an empty array(i initialized to null for debugging purposes); I think the problem is with my splice, because my output is just an empty array but i'm pretty sure my syntax is correct.

Input

a == [7, 10, 15, 54]

x = 99

Output:

[7, 10, 99, 15, 54]

```
function solution(a, x) {
 
 let count = a.length+1
 let mid = count/2
 let final = null
 if (mid % 2 === 0) {
         final = a.splice(a[mid], 0, x)
    } else {
        let middle = mid - 1
         final = a.splice(a[middle], 0, x)
    }
    
    return final
}
```

Edit:

I see the comment and have amended the code to this:

```
 let count = a.length+1
 let mid = count/2
 if (mid % 2 === 0) {
        a.splice(mid, 0, x)
    } else if (mid % 2 == 1) {
        let middle = mid-1
        a.splice(middle, 0, x)
    }
    return a
}
```

but this input fails because it doesn't want to insert the new value?

**Input:

a: [64, 38, 22, 27, 62, 41]
x: 90

Output:

[64, 38, 22, 27, 62, 41]

Expected Output:

[64, 38, 22, 90, 27, 62, 41]**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#return_value

Comment: As Phil commented, if you read the doc,you can find that **If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading offical document of [**splice()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice),we can find below description:

> Return value
> An array containing the deleted elements.
> If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned.
> **If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.**

Since you are not delete element,that's the reason,so you need to return the element directly

```js
function solution(a, x) {
 
 let count = a.length+1
 let mid = count/2
 if (mid % 2 === 0) {
   a.splice(mid, 0, x)
  } else {
   let middle = mid - 1
   a.splice(middle, 0, x)
  }
    
  return a
}

let data = [7, 10, 15, 54,55]
let x = 99
console.log(solution(data,x))
```

Answer (score 0):

First `splice` modify the original array. So you will have to return the original array and there is no need of `final` variable here. Secondly you have to use `Math.floor` or `Math.ceil` as `mid - 1` will still be a floating point number and lastly `a[middle]` in `a.splice(a[middle]...)` need to be replaced only with `middle`

```js
function solution(a, x) {

  let count = a.length + 1
  let mid = count / 2
  let final = null
  if (mid % 2 === 0) {
    a.splice(a[mid], 0, x)
  } else {
    let middle = Math.ceil(mid - 1);
    a.splice(middle, 0, x)
  }
  return a;
}


console.log(solution([7, 10, 15, 54], 99))
```